# How to Pass Array Object between view controllers by reference

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to pass an Array Object between 2 view controllers.  But I want the Array to be passed as a Reference and not copied.  I know if I was using a function locally, I can use "inout" and "&" based on the examples I found.

But I what I want to do is slightly different.  I want to assign the Array in VC1 directly to the Array object in VC2 as a reference.  Here is my code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "vc2" {

        let vc2 = segue.destinationViewController as! ProfileVC

        vc2.data = &self.data       //I know this line doesn't work, how would I go about it?

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift array are struct, so they will get copied.

The simplest way would be to use an object instead of a struct. So I would use a NSMutableArray instead.

With that you will have all the power of mutability at your finger tips ;-)